# CakePHP - Manual login

Tags: cakephp, authentication

I have an application developed with CakePHP, where I'm using the AuthComponent for Authentication and Authorization.

I'm making an action where the user can register on the application using Facebook.

I used HybridAuth to integrate Facebook with my application and I get the user data information to manipulate.

Now, I'm receiving the data correctly, but when I try to force a manual login and redirect the user to an authorized page, the user receives the authentication error.

My code:

```
$this->Auth->login($user_exists['User']);
$this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
```

Where $user_exists['User'] is equal to:
    $user_exists = $this->User->findByUsername($profile->email);

Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong and why CakePHP won't accept my data to make a forced login?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of CakePHP are you using? Also, did you try it like this; `$this->Auth->login($user_exists);`? I'm not familiar with the `HybridAuth` plugin, so cannot answer if this is the right approach in combination with that plugin

Comment: What exactly does the `$user_exists['User']` array contain? Add `debug($user_exists['User']);` before the login method to find out.

Comment: The debug of $user_exists: http://bin.cakephp.org/saved/102118

I'm using CakePHP v2.3.4.

I tried just the $user_exists, on ->login().

The HybridAuth is just to get the user informations from the Facebook API, has nothing to do with the AuthComponent.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that. Are you sure the user is authorized to access the page they are being redirected to? Check if the session was created by adding `debug($this->Auth->user()); exit;` after the login but before the redirect. If the users info is displayed then the user is logged in and your problem is access control.

Answer (score 0):

> Where $user_exists['User'] is equal to: $user_exists

That is your problem right there.
Those cannot be equal since the latter contains a deep array with

```
'User' => array(...)
```

and the first one is directly the array(...)

So make sure you pass in the (flat) User array directly.

```
->login($data)
```

with

```
$data = array('id' => 1, 'username' => 'foo, ...)
```

Comment: I tried with $user_exists only, and with $data but not worked.

If i comment the $this->Auth->login(), and try after that debug the AuthComponent::user(), i receive de user data.

Is like the AuthComponent::login() arrest the authentication to the action only. If i redirect the user, the authentication don't work. But if i go back to the connect action again, the authentication works.

Crazy, no?!

Comment: so you are already logged in when you call the login() method? in this case the method will return false and the manual login will probably not work.

Comment: No, i'm not logged in when i call the login() method, because when i redirect to an restricted area, the AuthComponent says i'm not logged.

Comment: "If i comment the $this->Auth->login(), and try after that debug the AuthComponent::user(), i receive de user data." Which means, that you are already logged in... Maybe some callback did that already some point earlier in script execution.